# Applying my own css classes in wp_menus 3?

Tags: customization

Have this function :

```
class my_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {

            global $wp_query;
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

            $class_names = $value = '';

            $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

            $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item));
            $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';

            $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args);
            $id = strlen($id) ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . '>';

            $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
        }

    }
```

I need to add my own counter instead of item->ID to add $myCounter(that will increment).

This :

```
$id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args);
```

To this :

```
$id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $myCounter, $item, $args);
```

I want to adjust to crazy css menu.How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi *@user1147* - Can you please change the title of this post to describe what the question is about? The answers on the site will benefit so many more people if they can see from the question titles if the question is same as the issue they are having, or not. Based on your current title I don't really have a clue what this question is about and don't have the time right now to read through the code to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry MikeSchinkel,I change the title,sorry on my bad english.

Comment: *@user1147* - Thank you, and apologize, I didn't realize you were ESL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to modify walker or hook into it unmodified?

Since there is filter provided for that id, it is easy to hook into. Try this:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'modify_menu_item_id' );

function modify_menu_item_id( $text ) {

    static $myCounter;

    if( !isset( $myCounter ) )
         $myCounter = 0;

    return 'menu-item-' . ++$myCounter;
}
```

**Update** Changing walker

```
 // add to start of start_el method
        static $myCounter;
        if( !isset( $myCounter ) )
            $myCounter = 0;
```

and

```
// change id lines to this
        $id = $args->depth ? 'menu-item-' . $item->ID : 'menu-item-' . ++$myCounter;
        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', $id, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen($id) ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';
```

I tried to exclude sub-menus by checking for current depth and I think it should work properly with multiple menus because each will get new instance of walker object.

Comment: I need also to modify walker,need to put submenus out of menus ul.Will try your code.Thanks.

Comment: I there a way to do this,but to modify walker?

Comment: Do you need one global counter or have it reset for every submenu? Latter seems tricky...

Comment: do not need for submenus,just for top menu,and need to put submenu out of top menus ul.finally beginning to understand how this works,thank you.

Comment: I had updated answer with how it might work for walker. Please test properly in your setup before use.

Comment: It works great,except the depth,the counter is also applied on the submenu items.I will try to fix this.Thank you

Comment: no,no,my mistake,it works perfectly,I didn't change depth to 1 to exclude submenus.Thanks.

Comment: But it is a little bit tricky to put submenu out of menu ul.

Comment: Ok,question,is it smart to modify function,or it is better to hook it ?

Comment: It depends. If this is your own code it is simpler to modify it. If this is third party code that is likely to get updated or something - it is better to make use of hook.

Comment: Ok,do you have idea,how to put submenu <ul> out of menu <ul>,think that will need to modify wp_nav_menu function,or to write a hook,...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _put out of_. If this is not related to your counter question please create new question for it.

Comment: it is with counter question,crazy mootools,css menu,trying to convert it to wp menu :) I need this kind of output for wp_nav_menu <ul class="main-menu"><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul><ul class="submenu"><li>Item sub 1</li><li>Item sub 2</li><li>Item sub 3</li></ul> Thanks